Chart disappears when adding first point or line in handleAddTrendLineButtonClick or handleAddLineB, reappears on next price tick - lightweight-charts
I'm using the lightweight-charts library in a React application to create a financial chart. I've implemented functionality to add support/resistance lines and trend lines on the chart using handleAddLineButtonClick and handleAddTrendLineButtonClick respectively. However, I'm encountering an issue where the chart disappears when I add the first point or line. The chart only reappears when there is at least one new price tick.
There are no such problems when adding the following lines
What could be causing the chart to disappear, and how can I fix this issue so that the chart remains visible when adding lines or points?
The project is available at: https://github.com/Tciganskybaron/TradingView
import { createChart, ColorType } from 'lightweight-charts';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import styles from './Chart.module.css';
import useChartData from '../../hooks/useChartData';
import useResize from '../../hooks/useResize';
import useChart from '../../store/chart';
import { LineSwitcher } from '../index';

export function Chart(props) {
    const {
        colors: {
            backgroundColor = 'white',
            textColor = 'black',
            candleUpColor = '#4CAF50',
            lineColor = '#2962FF',
            candleDownColor = '#F44336',
            areaTopColor = '#2962FF',
            areaBottomColor = 'rgba(41, 98, 255, 0.28)',
        } = {},
    } = props;
    const { interval, coin, chartType, isAddingLine, setIsAddingLine, isDrawingTrendLine, setIsDrawingTrendLine, trendLinePoints, setTrendLinePoints } = useChart((state) => state);

    const chartContainerRef = useRef();
        const chartRef = useRef(null);
    const seriesRef = useRef(null);
    const linesRef = useRef([]);
        const trendLineSeriesRef = useRef(null);

    const width = useResize();

    const { data, isLoading } = useChartData(interval, coin, chartType, width);
  

    useEffect(() => {
        const newChart = createChart(chartContainerRef.current, {
            layout: {
                background: { type: ColorType.Solid, color: backgroundColor },
                textColor,
            },
            width: chartContainerRef.current.clientWidth,
            height: chartContainerRef.current.clientHeight,
            localization: {
                locale: 'en-US',
            }
        });

        newChart.timeScale().fitContent();
        chartRef.current = newChart;

        const handleResize = () => {
            if (chartRef.current) {
                chartRef.current.applyOptions({ width: chartContainerRef.current.clientWidth, height: chartContainerRef.current.clientHeight });
                chartRef.current.timeScale().fitContent();
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
            newChart.remove();
        };
    }, [backgroundColor, textColor]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (chartRef.current) {
            if (seriesRef.current) {
                chartRef.current.removeSeries(seriesRef.current);
            }

            const newSeries = chartType === 'candlestick'
                ? chartRef.current.addCandlestickSeries({
                    upColor: candleUpColor,
                    downColor: candleDownColor,
                    borderVisible: false,
                    wickUpColor: candleUpColor,
                    wickDownColor: candleDownColor,
                })
                : chartRef.current.addAreaSeries({ lineColor, topColor: areaTopColor, bottomColor: areaBottomColor });

            seriesRef.current = newSeries;
        }
    }, [chartType, candleUpColor, candleDownColor, lineColor, areaTopColor, areaBottomColor]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (seriesRef.current && !isLoading && data.length > 0) {
            seriesRef.current.setData(data);
            chartRef.current.timeScale().fitContent();
        }
    }, [data, isLoading]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (chartRef.current) {
            chartRef.current.applyOptions({ width: chartContainerRef.current.clientWidth, height: chartContainerRef.current.clientHeight });
            chartRef.current.timeScale().fitContent();
        }
    }, [width]);

    const addSupportResistanceLine = useCallback((event) => {
        if (chartRef.current && isAddingLine) {
            const boundingRect = chartContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            const y = event.clientY - boundingRect.top;

            const price = seriesRef.current.coordinateToPrice(y);
            if (price) {
                const line = chartRef.current.addLineSeries();
                line.setData([{ time: data[0].time, value: price }, { time: data[data.length - 1].time, value: price }]);
                linesRef.current.push(line);
            }
            setIsAddingLine(false);
        }
    }, [isAddingLine, setIsAddingLine, data]);

    const startTrendLine = useCallback((event) => {
        if (chartRef.current) {
            const boundingRect = chartContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = event.clientX - boundingRect.left;
            const y = event.clientY - boundingRect.top;

            const price = seriesRef.current.coordinateToPrice(y);
            const time = chartRef.current.timeScale().coordinateToTime(x);

            if (price !== null && time !== null) {
                setTrendLinePoints([{ time, value: price }]);
                trendLineSeriesRef.current = chartRef.current.addLineSeries();
            }
        }
    }, []);

    const finishTrendLine = useCallback((event) => {
        if (chartRef.current && trendLinePoints.length === 1) {
            const boundingRect = chartContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = event.clientX - boundingRect.left;
            const y = event.clientY - boundingRect.top;

            const price = seriesRef.current.coordinateToPrice(y);
            const time = chartRef.current.timeScale().coordinateToTime(x);

            if (price !== null && time !== null) {
                const finalTrendLinePoints = [trendLinePoints[0], { time, value: price }];
                trendLineSeriesRef.current.setData(finalTrendLinePoints);
                linesRef.current.push(trendLineSeriesRef.current);
                setIsDrawingTrendLine(false);
                setTrendLinePoints([]);
            }
        }
    }, [trendLinePoints]);

    const updateTrendLine = useCallback((event) => {
        if (chartRef.current && trendLinePoints.length === 1) {
            const boundingRect = chartContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = event.clientX - boundingRect.left;
            const y = event.clientY - boundingRect.top;

            const price = seriesRef.current.coordinateToPrice(y);
            const time = chartRef.current.timeScale().coordinateToTime(x);

            if (price !== null && time !== null) {
                const updatedPoints = [trendLinePoints[0], { time, value: price }];
                trendLineSeriesRef.current.setData(updatedPoints);
            }
        }
    }, [trendLinePoints]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleChartClick = (event) => {
            if (isAddingLine) {
                addSupportResistanceLine(event);
            } else if (isDrawingTrendLine) {
                if (trendLinePoints.length === 0) {
                    startTrendLine(event);
                } else if (trendLinePoints.length === 1) {
                    finishTrendLine(event);
                }
            }
        };

        const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
            if (isDrawingTrendLine && trendLinePoints.length === 1) {
                updateTrendLine(event);
            }
        };

        if (chartContainerRef.current) {
            chartContainerRef.current.addEventListener('click', handleChartClick);
            chartContainerRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
        }

        return () => {
            if (chartContainerRef.current) {
                chartContainerRef.current.removeEventListener('click', handleChartClick);
                chartContainerRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
            }
        };
    }, [addSupportResistanceLine, startTrendLine, finishTrendLine, updateTrendLine, isAddingLine, isDrawingTrendLine, trendLinePoints]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (coin) {
            handleRemoveLinesButtonClick();
        }
    }, [coin]);

    const handleAddLineButtonClick = () => {
        setIsAddingLine(true);
    };

    const handleAddTrendLineButtonClick = () => {
        setIsDrawingTrendLine(true);
    };

    const handleRemoveLinesButtonClick = useCallback(() => {
        linesRef.current.forEach(line => chartRef.current.removeSeries(line));
        linesRef.current = [];
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <LineSwitcher 
                handleAddLineButtonClick={handleAddLineButtonClick} 
                handleAddTrendLineButtonClick={handleAddTrendLineButtonClick}
                handleRemoveLinesButtonClick={handleRemoveLinesButtonClick} 
                selectedValue={isAddingLine ? 'addLine' : isDrawingTrendLine ? 'addTrendLine' : null}
            />
            <div ref={chartContainerRef} className={styles.chart}/>
        </div>
    );
}


optimized useCallback everything I could, checked all dependencies in useEffect
